# iOS Unit Testing: Wait for Time Interval with Expectations

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode6

I'm trying to update my asynchronous unit tests to use the new `XCTestExpectation` interface instead of manually spinning the run loop.

My unit tests previously utilized the functions `waitForBlock`, `finishBlock`, and `waitForTimeInterval:` which is simply a convenience method that called `finishBlock` after the specified time. I'm trying to update this setup to use expectations.

The tests that were utilizing `waitForBlock` + `finishBlock` semantics are all working just as expected after being replaced with `waitForExpectationsWithTime:handler:` and `fulfill`, but my solution to replace `waitForTimeInterval:` doesn't seem to be working.

```
- (void)waitForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"wait"];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [expectation fulfill];
    });

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:delay + 1 handler:nil];
}
```

---

Edit:

Seems like that code actually *does* work... so this was probably just Xcode 6 screwing with me this afternoon.

---

I feel like it should be fairly straight-forward: Create an expectation, set up an asynchronous block that fulfills is, and wait. However, the `dispatch_after` block is never invoked.

My hunch is that `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler:` blocks its current thread, which is the main queue, so the run loop never gets around to its asynchronous blocks. That seems reasonable, but I'm having trouble coming up with a different way to implement this functionality.

I'm looking for either 1) additional information about `XCTestExpectation` that might reveal a workaround, or 2) a different idea for implementing this functionality.

Comment: Curious why you are doing it this way, wouldn't you want to not fulfill the expectations after some predefined delay, but rather right when your async tasks are completed?

Comment: Also, the code you provided seems to work fine for me... https://www.dropbox.com/s/lj61uwpbznyruaq/Screenshot%202014-09-25%2022.43.36.png?dl=0

Comment: 1) I'll grant you that the need for this functionality is a bit of a code smell, but some of our background tasks are fire-and-forget, without an asynchronous callback. In these cases we ensure the background task completes by just waiting for a small time interval before verifying the resulting state.

Comment: 2) You're right, I have to chalk this question up to Xcode 6 being possessed this afternoon. I dropped this code back into my implementation and now it runs as expected. No idea whatsoever.

Comment: Im having the same problem, did you find a solution with GCD yet?

Comment: It seems to be working if dispatch_async is called with dispatch_get_global_queue, but I don't know if it's safe to call expectation.fulfill() not from main thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used XCTestExpectation in a number of projects for all sorts of async web and GCD stuff... AFAIK, something like the following is what seems to be the most common usage:

```
- (void)testExample {
    // create the expectation with a nice descriptive message
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"The request should successfully complete within the specific timeframe."];

    // do something asyncronously
    [someObject doAsyncWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger yourReturnValue) {
        // now that the async task it done, test whatever states/values you expect to be after this is
        // completed
        NSInteger expectedValue = 42;
        XCTAssert(yourReturnValue == expectedValue, @"The returned value doesn't match the expected value.");

        // fulfill the expectation so the tests can complete
        [expectation fulfill];
    }];

    // wait for the expectations to be called and timeout after some
    // predefined max time limit, failing the test automatically
    NSTimeInterval somePredefinedTimeout = 3;
    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:somePredefinedTimeout handler:nil];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite address the question posed, but you took the time and the question itself isn't really of much value, so enjoy your points. :-) Cheers.

Comment: I thought it fell under "a different idea for implementing this functionality." :) Thanks

Answer (score 10):

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` doesn't seem to work in Xcode 7 UI Tests, the completion handler is never called. `performSelector` is no longer available in Swift, but there are two other workarounds:

1. Using a timer

   ```
   var waitExpectation: XCTestExpectation?

   func wait(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
       waitExpectation = expectationWithDescription("wait")
       NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(duration, target: self,
           selector: Selector("onTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
       waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(duration + 3, handler: nil)
   }

   func onTimer() {
       waitExpectation?.fulfill()
   }
   ```
2. Run the block on global queue (it works, but probably unsafe as it's not documented anywhere that XCTestExpectation is thread-safe).

   ```
   func wait(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
       let expectation = expectationWithDescription("wait")
       let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
           Int64(duration * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
       dispatch_after(dispatchTime,
           dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
           expectation.fulfill()
       }
       waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(duration + 3, handler: nil)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` works as expected, though I'm still not sure why. If anyone has an idea as to why GCD's `dispatch_after` doesn't work, please provide an additional answer and I will accept it. For now, this setup seems to work as expected:

```
- (void)waitForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"wait"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(fulfillExpectation:) withObject:expectation afterDelay:delay];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:delay + 1 handler:nil];
}

- (void)fulfillExpectation:(XCTestExpectation *)expectation
{
    [expectation fulfill];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In one of my Unit test cases I needed to test the running of a method in my main app code, which should trigger a timer in about 1 second to call another method in the app. I used `XCTestExpectation` wait and `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter` as a mechanism to stop and wait before I check the result. The following code is a snippet in Swift 3 / 4:

```
    <call the main app method which will trigger a timer event>

    // wait
    let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "test")
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2.5)

    <check the result of the timer event>
```